# Lista de Figuras formada por nome+número

Tags: latex

Utilizei o modelo [risethesis](https://github.com/yguarata/risethesis) para a criação de minha dissertação, mas ela não se adequa a abnt quanto às listas (figuras, tabelas...).

Por exemplo, a lista de figuras está sendo apresentada como:

```
1 Legenda1 .............. 34
2 Legenda2 .............. 35
```

(na verdade aparecia listada por capítulos (ex: 1.1, 2.1) mas isso eu já ajustei).

E eu preciso que seja nomeada como:

```
Figura 1 - Legenda1 ................34
Figura 2 - Legenda2 ................35
```

Answer (score 3):

Tenta utilizar esse comando no preâmbulo ([código original](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables)):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
% para figuras
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figura. } % coloca antes do número
\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{: }  % coloca depois do número
% ajusta o espaçamento
\newlength{\mylen}
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum\cftfigaftersnum}
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen}
```

Também dá uma lida nesses dois artigos do Tex Stackexchange (em inglês), que a dúvida esclarecida é a mesma

- [Adding word 'Table' before each entry in list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20337/adding-word-table-before-each-entry-in-list-of-tables)
- [How to change the numbering style in list of table and list of
  figures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419103/how-to-change-the-numbering-style-in-list-of-table-and-list-of-figures)

A propósito, você conhece o [ABNTeX](https://www.abntex.net.br/)? Com ele você consegue fazer documentos em LaTeX já formatados nas normas da ABNT.